# how to change the font properties(size, color,style) of the pdf document in UIWebView CGPDFDocumentRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fonts, uiwebview, cgpdfdocument

i am doing one eBook reader app for iphone in objective c ,i have tried 2 methods of loading pdf document using UIWebView and CGPDFDocumentRef but i am not getting how to change the font properties(size, color,style) of the pdf document in either of the methods(UIWebView and CGPDFDocumentRef ), can any one help me out,how to change font property in UIWebView as well as in CGPDFDocumentRef, thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. This function only give you a way to open it and others aspects. But, PDF is unable to edit in any operate system. So I don't think you can do this things.

What you can do is create a new PDF. And it isn't very easy... You can start with this: [Writing text to a PDF via from an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986427/writing-text-to-a-pdf-via-from-an-nsstring)