# How can I load an existing PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, quartz-2d

i asked this previously but I think people got the wrong idea:
I'm not trying to generate a PDF from scratch; I'm trying to load and draw onto the screen using Quartz 2d an existing PDF file : any guidance / examples would be very much appreciated

This was my previous post : 
[How to open and View PDF using Quartz 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126974/how-to-open-and-view-pdf-using-quartz-2d)

Comment: [Here is your solution](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/)

Comment: Thank you - This is perfect, I wish you had it as a answer, so I could mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: Added answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a great tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/) how to render PDF using `CoreGraphics`

Answer (score 3):

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pdf-reader-core

Use this control. It does a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with rendering the PDF into an UIImage and displaying that (a good solution if you don't provide zooming functionality, or if you are happy to constrain zooming to a limited extent using the UIImage inside a UIScrollView), then this project is very good and does disk caching for improved performance:

https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF